# How to render razor view as string in .net core web api?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .net core web api application. I need to send out the email using razor view. I cannot get razor view as string to send out the email. 
I get the exception at Engine.Razor.RunCompile(razorView, "templateKey" + DateTime.Now.Ticks, null, model);

Below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MyProject.Api.Models;
using RazorEngine;
using RazorEngine.Templating;

namespace MyProject.Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AppointmentBookingController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public AppointmentBookingController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetViewAsString")]
        public string GetViewAsString()
        {
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

            BaseHttpRequestModel model = new BaseHttpRequestModel
            {
                LanguageID = "ABC"
            };

            string razorView = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(contentRootPath + @"\Views\EmailTemplates\Test.cshtml");
            Engine.Razor.RunCompile(razorView, "templateKey" + DateTime.Now.Ticks, null, model);

            return razorView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to supply the model type instead of passing `null` when using a strongly typed model. You pass `null` in when using anonymous or dynamic types. Also return the output of `RunCompile`:

```
...
var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(razorView, "templateKey" + DateTime.Now.Ticks, model.GetType(), model);

return result;
```